# ¿Cómo guardo una contraseña en md5?

Tags: php, mysql, md5

Tengo este código con una tabla dinámica que me permite editar el campo mediante un `update` pero necesito que se actualice en md5. ¿Cómo lo puedo hacer?

fetch.php:

```
<?php
//fetch.php
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "registration_emp");
$columns = array('username','password');

$query = "SELECT * FROM users ";

if(isset($_POST["search"]["value"]))
{
 $query .= '
 WHERE username LIKE "%'.$_POST["search"]["value"].'%" 
 OR password LIKE "%'.$_POST["search"]["value"].'%" 
 ';
}

if(isset($_POST["order"]))
{
 $query .= 'ORDER BY '.$columns[$_POST['order']['0']['column']].' '.$_POST['order']['0']['dir'].' 
 ';
}
else
{
 $query .= 'ORDER BY id DESC ';
}

$query1 = '';

if($_POST["length"] != -1)
{
 $query1 = 'LIMIT ' . $_POST['start'] . ', ' . $_POST['length'];
}

$number_filter_row = mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($connect, $query));

$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query . $query1);

$data = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
 $sub_array = array();
 $sub_array[] = '<div contenteditable class="update" data-id="'.$row["id"].'" data-column="username">' . $row["username"] . '</div>';
 $sub_array[] = '<div contenteditable class="update" data-id="'.$row["id"].'" data-column="password">' . $row["password"] . '</div>';
 $sub_array[] = '<button type="button" name="delete" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs delete" id="'.$row["id"].'">Delete</button>';
 $data[] = $sub_array;
}

function get_all_data($connect)
{
 $query = "SELECT * FROM users";
 $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
 return mysqli_num_rows($result);
}

$output = array(
 "draw"    => intval($_POST["draw"]),
 "recordsTotal"  =>  get_all_data($connect),
 "recordsFiltered" => $number_filter_row,
 "data"    => $data
);

echo json_encode($output);

?>
```

update.php

```
<?php
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "registration_emp");
if(isset($_POST["id"]))
{
 $value = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["value"]);
 $query = "UPDATE users SET ".$_POST["column_name"]."='".$value."' WHERE id = '".$_POST["id"]."'";
 if(mysqli_query($connect, $query))
 {
  echo 'Data Updated';
 }
}
?>
```

Formulario:

```
   <form class="navbar-form navbar-left">
        <div class="form-group">
            <br>
        <li><a class="btn btn-success btn-xs" href="registration/register.php" style="color:#fff"> registrar un nuevo Admin</a></li>

    </div>
    <form class="navbar-form navbar-left">
        <div class="form-group">
            <br>
            <li><a class="btn btn-success btn-xs" href="registration/register.php" style="color:#fff">registrar nuevo empleado de estacion de servicio</a></li>
    </div>



      </form>

      <ul id="ejm2" class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">


        <li><a  href="reporteExel.php">descargar reporte Exel</a></li>
        <li><a  href="reporteWord.php">descargar reporte Word</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
</header>
<br><br><br>
  <div class="container box">
   <h1 align="center">zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz </h1>
   <br />
   <div class="table-responsive">
   <br />

    <br />
    <div id="alert_message"></div>
    <table id="user_data" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
     <thead>
      <tr>
       <th>nombre de usuario</th>
       <th>contraseña</th>
       <th></th>
      </tr>
     </thead>

    </table>
    <a class="btn btn-warning" href="index.php">Regresar</a>
    <br> <br>
   </div>

  </div>

 </body>
</html>


<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" >
 $(document).ready(function(){

  fetch_data();

  function fetch_data()
  {
   var dataTable = $('#user_data').DataTable({
    "processing" : true,
    "serverSide" : true,
    "order" : [],
    "ajax" : {
     url:"fetch.php",
     type:"POST"
    }
   });
  }

  function update_data(id, column_name, value)
  {
   $.ajax({
    url:"update.php",
    method:"POST",
    data:{id:id, column_name:column_name, value:value},
    success:function(data)
    {
     $('#alert_message').html('<div class="alert alert-success">'+data+'</div>');
     $('#user_data').DataTable().destroy();
     fetch_data();
    }
   });
   setInterval(function(){
    $('#alert_message').html('');
   }, 5000);
  }

  $(document).on('blur', '.update', function(){
   var id = $(this).data("id");
   var column_name = $(this).data("column");
   var value = $(this).text();
   update_data(id, column_name, value);
  });

  $('#add').click(function(){
   var html = '<tr>';
   html += '<td contenteditable id="data1"></td>';
   html += '<td contenteditable id="data2"></td>';
   html += '<td><button type="button" name="insert" id="insert" class="btn btn-success btn-xs">Insert</button></td>';
   html += '</tr>';
   $('#user_data tbody').prepend(html);
  });

  $(document).on('click', '#insert', function(){
   var username = $('#data1').text();
   var password = $('#data2').text();
   if(username != '' && password != '')
   {
    $.ajax({
     url:"insert.php",
     method:"POST",
     data:{username:username, password:password},
     success:function(data)
     {
      $('#alert_message').html('<div class="alert alert-success">'+data+'</div>');
      $('#user_data').DataTable().destroy();
      fetch_data();
     }
    });
    setInterval(function(){
     $('#alert_message').html('');
    }, 5000);
   }
   else
   {
    alert("Both Fields is required");
   }
  });

  $(document).on('click', '.delete', function(){
   var id = $(this).attr("id");
   if(confirm("Are you sure you want to remove this?"))
   {
    $.ajax({
     url:"delete.php",
     method:"POST",
     data:{id:id},
     success:function(data){
      $('#alert_message').html('<div class="alert alert-success">'+data+'</div>');
      $('#user_data').DataTable().destroy();
      fetch_data();
     }
    });
    setInterval(function(){
     $('#alert_message').html('');
    }, 5000);
   }
  });
 });
</script>
<br><br>
<br><br>
<br><br>
```

Comment: Parece que el código es para algo interno de administración, pero lo que compartes presenta vulnerabilidades graves de seguridad: puede sufrir ataques de inyección SQL, tiene problemas de autenticación/autorización, manejo inseguro de credenciales, gestión de errores/registros inexistente... y lo que te planteas (usar MD5 para encriptar contraseñas) es algo que no se recomienda.

Comment: respuesta corta: no lo haces,  md5 y sha-1 son demasiado rápidos para hashear claves

Comment: si quieres hacerlo asi solo pon md5(nuevoValor) y reemplazalo por el anterior en tu update